# Put data to dynamic content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing simple application on HTML and jQuery. It connectes to the ASP.NEt server with signalR. I have login page where the user authenticates. After success authentication content of my `<div id="body"></div>` is updating with **load()** method:

```
$("#body").load("_ListView.html",InitListPage());
```

Content of _ListView.html:

```
<table id="driversList" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Login</th>
    <th>Some Data</th>
    <th>Another Data</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>

</table>
```

What I want is to update content of my table after it has been loaded. But jQuery doesn't see my dynamic content. Even sample code wan't to work:

```
function InitListPage(){

 $("#driversList").css("border","3px solid red");
}
```

How can I resolve it ot maybe I'm doing wrong at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the `function reference` as a `callBack` function,

```
$("#body").load("_ListView.html",InitListPage);
```

You are calling it there, so `undefined` will be returned and passed as the second parameter. That is the problem with your code.

Comment: can't belive it's so easy -_-

Comment: @dantey89 Glad to help :) Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer. As it will be helpful for future visitors to spot it has helped you. And this is not a compulsion. :)